# Are Friend Safari Pokémon gender locked?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have this Ponyta, Pyroar, Braixen Safari and have been trying to get a male Pyroar off it. At some point, I noticed something must be wrong and paid attention to the genders I was encountering, here are the results:

- Out of 7 Ponytas, 1 was male
- Out of 15 Braixen, 1 was female
- Out of 30+ Pyroar, none was male.

This leads me to the conclusion that the Pokémon in the Friend Safari are at least very strongly shifted towards one gender, in some cases possibly even locked to one gender.

Can anyone confirm or disprove this theory? I don't want to spend hours searching for that male Pyroar if it just doesn't exist...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In two of your three cases, the Pokémon in question has a natural bias against your specific gender requirements:

- Ponyta is 50% male, 50% female
- Braixen is 87.5% male, 12.5% female
- Pyroar is 25% male, 75% female

There doesn't appear to be any additional skewing applied by the Friend Safari, at least not from the incredibly small data sets you've given here.

Comment: So just bad luck? Because 1/(0.75^30) = 5600

Comment: Assuming you don't encounter any other Pokémon in the meantime, then yes, that would be the chance of hitting 30 female Pyroar in a row. Probabilities don't always work that way, though...

Comment: I'm having some insane bad luck streak, then... I could have encountered like 10 shinies by now with those odds. I did find one, but yeah...

Comment: @scenia The most important part to note is that the chance, however low, is not 0%. That's all that matters if you're looking for something :)

Comment: Confirming, I found one. It took no less than 37 encounters, I've never experienced this kind of streak in a game. Astounding PRNG capabilities... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @scenia The chances of Rock Slide and Heat Wave both missing both targets in a Double Battle are 0.01%, which is about the same as your streak of female Pyroar. Just more painful. Luckily for me, I was on the receiving end of that!